# Call js function to change css color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change color on click with function, but there is a problem, when I click on disadvantage must be red, when I click on average must be yellow, when I click on advantage must be green... also when I click on one thing other must lose focus- backrground color... how to do this with function

```
function colored() {                
$(this).css('background-color','#C90');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/15/

Comment: sorry the jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/EC44Z/15/

Comment: First of all, the handler should not be bound with an `onClick` HTML attribute. jQuery provides an easy way to do that, as demonstrated by the other answers. However, another problem with your original code is that `colored` is not in the global scope, as the fiddle is configured to wrap all JavaScript code inside an `onLoad` handler (see left panel). Therefore, the `colored` function wasn't even found when a click was received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would recommend using CSS styles for this type of functionality. So you're colors should be defined as classes, for example:

```
.is-advantage { background-color: #ccc; }
```

You should then implement some sort of event handler for your click event. In the jsfiddle provided, I don't see where your function will be called at all. You likely want something like:

```
// change the class each time the button is clicked
$('.button').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-advantage');
});
```

You can use functions like [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/), [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to change out what class(es) are currently set for the button.

Answer (score 0):

You are not attaching the click handlers to your HTML elements

For example if you want the link called disabled to change background color:

Assuming you are interested in changing the background color for following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="price_quality_dis" class="ca_button" onClick="colored();">Disadvantage</a>
```

You will need to provide a click handler as follows:

```
$('#price_quality_dis').click(function(){
  $(this).css('background-color','#C90');
});
```

Also you should use class attribute to decorate your a tags to group together the links which should have a same background color upon clicking

An example is: http://jsfiddle.net/XUXwJ/

Comment: yes, but also I need to put this in function becouse I need to call my colored function in other function...

Comment: I see ... then your colored function needs to know which element it should change the bacvkground color for ... 'this' makes no sense inside this function ... I have edited the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/XUXwJ/

Comment: yes, but the advantage when I click on adventage nothing happend

Comment: that is because I left that as an exercise for you :-)

Comment: you will need to provide seperate event handlers for each type of elements that you want to change behavior for ... and hence grouping them in class is better than using ids ...

Comment: yes thanks I integrated your code into mine but isnt work like I need... please see http://jsfiddle.net/SVPY2/1/